# How to Run a Windows store app at startup if "open file location" option is not available?

Tags: windows, windows-10

While tryng to get the app "Maister Task" to run at startup I ran into the issue that, if the app is not already displayed in the startup manager, the method shown by the [Windows 10 documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/add-an-app-to-run-automatically-at-startup-in-windows-10-150da165-dcd9-7230-517b-cf3c295d89dd) to run apps at startup states that "If there isn't an option for Open file location, it means the app can't run at startup."
Is there a workarround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible workarround:

1. open "Run" (`Windows key + R`)
2. Type: `shell:AppsFolder`
3. Locate the app that you want to run at startup.
4. Right click on app icon and select "Create shortcut"
5. Select destination of the shortcut.
6. Open "Run" again and type `shell:startup`
7. Add the shortcut that you created in step 4 to this folder.

Now the program will be launched when Windows is started.